# Icons is missing after upgrade to Flutter 2.5.3

Tags: android, flutter, dart, icons

How can i fix missing icons in my application after i upgrade from 2.0.1 to Flutter 2.5.3 version.
(We can still press the button of the icons, but the icon it self is missing)

This is my pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4

  intl: ^0.17.0
  provider: ^6.0.1
  flutter_svg: ^0.23.0+1
  connectivity: ^3.0.6
  hexcolor: ^2.0.5
  path: ^1.8.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.1.0+1
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  qr_flutter: ^4.0.0
  http: ^0.13.4
  crypto: ^3.0.1
  image: ^3.0.8
  bitmap: ^0.1.2
  sembast: ^3.1.1
  path_provider: ^2.0.7
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  collection: ^1.15.0
  android_alarm_manager: ^2.0.2
  data_connection_checker: ^0.3.4
  flutter_switch: ^0.3.2
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+4
  email_validator: ^2.0.1
  numeric_keyboard: ^1.1.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
#  unique_identifier: ^0.0.3
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: false
  image_path: "assets/images/icon2.png"
```

This is the icons (back & search) in 2.0.1

[image: This is the icons in 2.0.1]

After i upgrade to 2.5.3 the icons is missing in all my app:

[image: After upgrade to 2.5.3]

Comment: Did you tried "flutter clean" in project after upgrade?

Comment: Yes i tried "Flutter Clean" but it doesnt work.